# hs.htmlExpand DOMElement with or w/o image

Tags: highslide

Doc - http://highslide.com/ref/hs.expand:

element - Reference to the HTML element that opens the expander. When hs.expand is used in an onclick attribute, this parameter will be this.

When I am using HS and DOMElement is an element (div, span, tr) that does NOT contain image => the zoom effect of the newly generating HS popup is starting from the whole surface of the element. But when the element contains inside an image => the zoom effect is starting from that image, instead of the whole surface of the element.

Please see an example here - http://projects.prowavegroup.ca/test2/hs/

How can I keep the effect to start from the whole surface of the element while having an image inside that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highslide is designed to expand from an element’s innerHTML image. As far as I know, the only way you can avoid this is to set the image as background image.

Comment: thanks, if you will find other solution than making image as a background - I would appreciate if you will share it.